# Store OpenID endpoint, OP-Local Identifier and realm?

Tags: openid

I'm about to create a datatbase table to store OpenID logins. I think I will include these three columns, in addition to the Claimed Identifier:

- [The OpenID endpoint](http://openid.net/specs/openid-authentication-2_0.html#terminology)
- [The OP-Local Identifier](http://openid.net/specs/openid-authentication-2_0.html#anchor49)
- [The realm](http://openid.net/specs/openid-authentication-2_0.html#realms)
- The OpenID version (1 or 2)

Do you store these fields?

Do you think it's reasonable to store these fields?, for the following reasons:

- The OpenID endpoint: So you know which OpenID Provider authenticated the user. Perhaps in the future you'll find out that one provider is not so very trustworthy, and then I think it's good to know if *someuser.example.com* was authenticated by that provider.
- The OP-Local Identifier: I think it allows me to keep track of the user, even if she changes her User-Supplied Identifier. (For example, if her User-Supplied Identifier is example.com/username, but she changes it to somewhereelse.com/username, then I think the OP-Local Identifier will remain unchanged (assuming the user continues using the same OpenID Provider).
- The realm: I'm building a multitenant webapp, and if I store the realm, it'll be easier to know if two seemingly different OpenID identifiers might represent the same person. ([Google uses directed identities](http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/OpenID.html#Response): your Claimed ID varies by realm. So the same user can have many different Claimed IDs.)
- The version: In case some security issue appears in the future, with some OpenID version, then it might be good to know which users might be affected.
- The realm and endpoint, for statistics gathering purposes.

(Can you think of some other OpenID related value I ought to store? For example, I want to identify provider. To do this, it suffice to store the endpoint? I don't need to store the provider's name?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- The OpenID endpoint: Trustworthy? How is a provider trustworthy (or not)? It isn't asserting anything about the data it doesn't own, so it can't possibly lie. Whether it behaves as you expect it to is another thing whatsoever. Besides, a provider could, for some reason, have different endpoints for each user (for example, `/server-username`).
- The OP-Local Identifier: You shouldn't (because the specification says so), but yes, in a very small number of cases, it would be successful. However, it is much more often to change your provider than to change your identity. And if you really want to change your identity, changing the provider (or registering a different account) isn't that hard. One case where it would help would be when the user would lose the domain name that hosts the claimed identity. However, it is much more likely for the provider to stop offering it's services, and you also need to prepare for that (for example, by offering to store multiple IDs for a single user, like SO). And if you're prepared for it, the single case where it would help is covered by another mechanism.
- The realm: I don't see how would that help you. From Google, you get two completely separate identifiers, with no possibility to correlate them, unless you require an email address (and why would you need the realm, then?).
- The version: Unlikely, and the version may change with the new request (because a provider might update). Nevertheless, if you really want to know which of your users might be affected, and somehow expect them to gain anything by reading about that on your website, then yes, it could be useful.

You've said that you want to identify the provider. However, as I've mentioned above, it's not possible to do so if the provider takes steps to avoid that. You could, for example, store it's domain name, but that's not perfect, since there might be other providers under the same domain (for example, several people hosting their own providers on a shared hosting).

In summary, my opinion is that storing these is a bad idea, for reasons stated above.

Comment: Okay, it's pointless to store the OP-Local Identifier. I didn't find any place in [the spec](http://openid.net/specs/openid-authentication-2_0.html) that stated I should not store it though. -- Actually, perhaps I'll store it anyway, in case I'll find it from a data mining point of view, in some weird manner. If not, ALTER TABLE DROP COLUMN is quickly done, some day in the future.

Comment: I didn't mention that I intend to store some of the data for statistics gathering purposes. E.g. I might want to know which realms have the most logins, and which endpoints and/or providers are the most common ones. (I added a list item to the question.)

Comment: Trustworthy endpoints: Actually I think that a provider can be "more trustworthy" than others. E.g. Google verifying Google mail addresses. That's not part of the OpenID spec though of course. -- I *think* I've actually read that a Gmail email address obtained from a Google endpoint is guaranteed to be owned by the person that owns the Claimed ID.  -- Can there be *un*trustworthy providers? What if evil Mallory sets up a provider to exploit some known bug in the OpenID client I use? To gain access to a user account?

Comment: A provider can always give itself access to the user's account, since it's the provider's decision whether to authenticate the user or not. So the user should indeed trust his provider. Your website, however, shouldn't care that much. As for gathering statistics -- storing realms may be a good idea in this case (although it isn't really related to the OpenID). Also, while it's not specifically said that you shouldn't store OP-Local ID, it is stated that the Claimed Identifier should be used -- that's what I meant, although it probably wasn't so clear.

Comment: I agree that data from Google can usually be more trusted than from other providers, but I prefer not to have special cases. Still, if you want to select the "trustworthy" ones (i.e. something like a whitelist) instead of the others (a blacklist), your approach may be somewhat effective. Still, you can't reliably detect a "bad" provider this way.

Comment: Hello again, thanks for the additional details.  --  I think it's reasonable to store (some of) the data mentioned, for statistical and debugging purposes, if nothing else. (Costs virtually nothing if you have a normalized database?) Thanks again for your answer which I just accepted  :-)